# How to properly type sagas

Tags: redux, flowtype, redux-saga

I am trying to type sagas. I am using the flow-typed definitions:
https://github.com/flowtype/flow-typed/blob/master/definitions/npm/redux-saga_v0.13.x/flow_v0.36.x-v0.37.x/redux-saga_v0.13.x.js

```
export function* fetchUsers(): Generator<IOEffect, void, any> {
  const users = yield call(UserApi.list)
  yield put(fetchUserSucc(users))
}
```

But flow keeps complaining:

> Identifier `IOEffect` Could not resolve name

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to import IOEffect from the libdef like this:

`import type { IOEffect } from 'redux-saga/effects';`

Source: https://github.com/flowtype/flow-typed/issues/645

Comment: It doesn't seem this is valid any more, getting "Cannot import `IOEffect` because there is no `IOEffect` export in `redux-saga/effects`." when I try to do that!

Answer (score 4):

Try using this:

```
import { type Saga } from 'redux-saga';

export function* fetchUsers(): Saga<void> {
  some logic...
}
```

It works right for me